# SQL query result monthly arrangement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have two tables

```
(1) MonthlyTarget {SalesManCode, TargetValue};

(2) MonthlySales  {SalesManCode, SaleDate, AchievedValue};
```

I have to make a query that produces a result like the following table:

```
{SalesManCode, JanTar, JanAch, FebTar, FebAch,....., DecTar, DecAch}
```

What should be the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What database are you using?  I have a stored procedure that simplifies doing that type of pivot for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 ...

If you are using SQL Server 2005:

Run this to install the [pivot_query procedure](http://dot-dash-dot.com/files/pivot_query.sql).

Here is an [example](http://dot-dash-dot.com/files/pivot_query_examples.sql) like you described, the output looks like:

```
SalesManCode April_Tar    April_Ach    February_Tar February_Ach January_Tar  January_Ach  March_Tar    March_Ach    
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ 
Bob          12000.000    9000.000     9000.000     9000.000     10000.000    11000.000    11000.000    10000.000    
Sara         12000.000    9200.000     9000.000     9300.000     10000.000    11500.000    11000.000    10200.000
```

Comment: How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Unfortunately the PIVOT command used in the stored procedure was introduced in SQL Server 2005 - so it won't work in SQL Server 2000 .. . I'll look around a bit.